# Invoke request to localhost immediately after servlet container startup

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, servlets

I'm looking to have my java web application call itself at a localhost URL immediately after the servlet container (be it tomcat, jetty, ...) begins accepting requests.

I'm using the java spring framework but I believe that's a "side issue" since it's really the servlet container's status that I need to be aware of.

As I understand it, spring initializes the application context with all its beans first, then maps the URLs and initializes the `DispatcherServlet` to handle the handling/filtering of requests.

I'm looking to find the "moment" when I can safely use a `RestTemplate` to call the server itself. Everything I've tried seems to be "too early" as it has resulted in `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused`--except for when I invoke it manually from a web browser via a controller endpoint--which succeeds.

I've tried using:

1. `javax.servlet.ServletContextListener` as per [How to invoke a method on a servlet or controller after the web container has successfully started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484186/how-to-invoke-a-method-on-a-servlet-or-controller-after-the-web-container-has-su#comment13554634_10484828)
2. `org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>`
3. a hacky custom servlet's init method with a "load-on-startup" after the `DispatcherServlet`

At some point in time, the servlet container must have to take over from spring's setup and "flip the switch" to "on". Also, I'd like to do this in a servlet container "agnostic" way so that I don't have specific tomcat/jetty code.

Here's the resttemplate exception. I'm running the app on port 9090 and my contextPath is 'openid-connect-provider'. 'foo' is a very simple GET endpoint that works, as I mentioned, when invoked after the servlet container is started.

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:9090/openid-connect-provider/foo": Connection refused; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:582)
...
```

The only other thing I can say is that these errors occur in my logs/console just before Jetty tells me that it's started:

```
[INFO] Started ServerConnector@1bcba9c7{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:9090}
[INFO] Started @13749ms
[INFO] Started Jetty Server
```

[update]
A bit more background. I'm implementing an OAuth2 Authorization Server (AS). My user credentials are in a separate database that I need to access through a separate service (which is an oauth2 resource server or RS). I need my AS to call the RS to authenticate users but I want to protect my RS with tokens granted by my AS. So, i need to setup my AS as a oauth2 client of itself so that it can call the RS securely. To do that, I want to dynamically register the application (with itself) to get client_id/client_secret credentials generated so that it can call my RS. Ideally, I'd want my user info to be in the same service and not to have to do this but this is a 6-month interim step.

Comment: The servlet container may or may not have already opened-up its TCP ports when your application loads, for example you may be *reloading* your webapp sometimes, and initially-loading it from a container restart other times, so this may be a bit chaotic for you. Is there no way to request an OAuth resource without using HTTP -- say, using a Java API that calls directly?

Comment: That's a good thought. The problem with using a Java api (which I could do) is that I anticipate that there may be more manual work than using, essentially, oauth2 sdk helpers that wrap the http calls needed. So far, handling the code upon the first request after starting up is acceptable and easy to implement for me.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this little trick at the end of your `ServletContextListener#contextStarted` event

```
new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(500);
            // Your client call.
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }).start();
```

You can adjust the sleep time.

Comment: Feels a bit ugly (i.e. there should be something more elegant) but i see what you're trying to do and it's worth a try at this point! I'll write back how it goes afterwards. Thanks.

Comment: Yep, it's certainly something ugly.. but sometimes, you don't have any solution other than being ugly

Comment: You said that these errors occurs just before jetty tells you that it's started, so, you try to access the resource url before jetty is notified that it's started. You have other solutions: may be schedule a thread that will post your client call after jetty is started.. otherwise, you have to grump into jetty's code

Comment: any ways, can you please notify me if you solved it ? i am interested in this problem

Comment: So, this works, but I'm concerned that if my high-traffic server get's hit with a request before this sleep is finished that the server won't be initialized properly (via the request) in time. Perhaps a listener on the first http request  (e.g. HttpSessionListener) to do this the first time. Downside: slower response to first request? Upvoting because this is a solution but I'm going to hold off on accepting it as I wait for a more elegant one.

Comment: Can you tell me why the app need to call itself ?

Comment: Yeah, the sessionListener listens for everytime a session is created, but you'll have many invocations since you said that your server is a hightraffic one...

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've decided to do (for now). Wait for the first request in order to guarantee that the servlet container is accepting requests. Then do the call once and disable it from doing it again until next startup.

```
public class PostStartInitilizationListener implements HttpSessionListener {

  private static volatile boolean isInitialized;

  @Override
  public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
    if (!isInitialized) { // because we don't want to do this on every session creation
      synchronized(this) { // prevent other threads from making the request as well
        isInitialized = true; // to immediately prevent any other sessionCreated events from making the request
        // the request
        ResponseEntity<String> entity = new RestTemplate().getForEntity("http://localhost:9090/openid-connect-provider/foo", String.class);
      }
    }
  }
}
```